# Debian: can not install php5-suhosin and php5-apc

Tags: debian, packages, alternative-php-cache, php, linux

Just ordered a new Debian server and for some reason can not install
php5-suhosin and php5-apc. Any ideas?

```
apt-get install php5-suhosin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-suhosin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-suhosin' has no installation candidate

=========================================

apt-get install php5-apc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-apc

php -v
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u4 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 14:37:41)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APC and suhosin are not available in stable repository.

you can install it from dotdeb repo, by adding following to your sources.list

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze-php54 all
```

also, you can install apc for php < 5.5 via PECL:

```
apt-get install php5-dev gcc make
pecl install apc
```

Comment: A very quick search shows it's not available for Wheezy, which his question indicates he's using.

Answer (score 1):

Suhosin hasn't been added to Wheezy's repositories (see: http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2013/04/msg00409.html) but APC is there, it's just called `php-apc`. (see: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/php-apc)

Answer (score 0):

Suhosin have their own repository which surely will be the most up to date. The preferred way of installing is to add that to your /apt/sources.list.d even if you have a debian version that provides the package.

See their documentation:
http://suhosin.org/stories/install.html